# How to get access token for twitter application hosted on a web server using oauth

Tags: python, twitter, oauth

I want to create an Twitter access token request in python for an application which will be hosted on a web sever.
I tried a few scripts but while they work fine on bare terminal, they face some error after deploying on a web server.
Kindly guide how to proceed after registering on twitter and getting the oauth keys.

Here is the code which I tried to deploy on Google App engine

```
import sys

import requests,sys
sys.path.insert(0,'requests_oauthlib')
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
from urlparse import parse_qs




import webapp2


MAIN_PAGE_HTML = """\
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
  <h3> Twitter Analysis</h3>
    <form action="/parser" method="post">
      Enter the words you want to perform analysis on :
      <div><input type="text" name="conten" ></input></div>
      <div><input type="submit" value="Analyse"></div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
"""



REQUEST_TOKEN_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
AUTHORIZE_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token="
ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"

CONSUMER_KEY = "xxxxxxxx"
CONSUMER_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"

OAUTH_TOKEN = ""
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = ""

def setup_oauth():
    """Authorize your app via identifier."""
    # Request token
    oauth = OAuth1(CONSUMER_KEY, client_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET)
    r = requests.post(url=REQUEST_TOKEN_URL, auth=oauth)
    print dir(r.content)
    credentials = parse_qs(r.content)
    print dir(credentials)
    resource_owner_key = credentials.get('oauth_token')[0]
    resource_owner_secret = credentials.get('oauth_token_secret')[0]

    # Authorize
    authorize_url = AUTHORIZE_URL + resource_owner_key
    print 'Please go here and authorize: ' + authorize_url

    verifier = raw_input('Please input the verifier: ')
    oauth = OAuth1(CONSUMER_KEY,
                   client_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
                   resource_owner_key=resource_owner_key,
                   resource_owner_secret=resource_owner_secret,
                   verifier=verifier)

    # Finally, Obtain the Access Token
    r = requests.post(url=ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, auth=oauth)
    credentials = parse_qs(r.content)
    token = credentials.get('oauth_token')[0]
    secret = credentials.get('oauth_token_secret')[0]

    return token, secret

def get_oauth():
    oauth = OAuth1(CONSUMER_KEY,
                client_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
                resource_owner_key=OAUTH_TOKEN,
                resource_owner_secret=OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
    return oauth

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.response.write(MAIN_PAGE_HTML)

class SignIn(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.response.write("success")

    def post(self):

        self.response.write("post")
        if not OAUTH_TOKEN:
            token, secret = setup_oauth()
            print "OAUTH_TOKEN: " + token
            print "OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET: " + secret
            print
        else:
            oauth = get_oauth()
            r = requests.get(url="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json", auth=oauth)
            print r.json()

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/parser',SignIn)
], debug=True)
```

Comment: Please give more details of your web server and your scripts. What oauth library are you using? e.g. rauth?